# Symfony2 error Expected end of string

Tags: database, symfony

Trying to run a query with symfony and I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 83: Error: Expected end of string, got 'username'
```

This code throws that error:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT username
            FROM BLOGBlogBundle:user
            WHERE username= :usrname'
        )->setParameter('usrname', $usr);
        $products = $query->getResult();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to work when you add in the alias

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT u.username
            FROM BLOGBlogBundle:user u
            WHERE u.username = :usrname')
    ->setParameter('usrname', $usr);

$products = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: You always need to define an alias.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is using `Exp` with `->set()` like `$qb->expr()`

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$q = $qb->update('models\User', 'u')
        ->set('u.username', $qb->expr()->literal($username))
        ->set('u.email', $qb->expr()->literal($email))
        ->where('u.id = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $editId)
        ->getQuery();
$p = $q->execute();
```